# Authentication Backends file

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-permissions

I wish to customize my authentication backends, i'm a beginner in django and i want to practice, but i am alittle confused. I red the documentation but for their example and for each example i found, no one says where you should write the class. Do you have to add your class in the default django backends.py? or do you have to create your own backends.py and add it after to Settings.py?
Another thing, i want to know if the authorizations and permissions have to be written in the same customized backends.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make your own, it doesn't matter where you put it as long as it makes sense for you.. Then you just update your settings to use the right `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`.

Overwriting django's own makes no sense since you'd never be able to (easily) update django and you'd most likely break something unintentionally.